# Add two sets of coordinates in Python using a class?

Tags: python, function, class

I'm trying to add two sets of coordinates using a class in python. This is what I have so far.

```py
class Position:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self, x):
        self.x = self + x
```

And in a different program to run the class I have

```
A = Position(1, 1)
B = Position(2, 3)
A.add(B)
A.print()
```

So I am trying to add A and B to get (3,4). How would I do that using the add class? I don't know what to set for the parameters or what to put in the body of the function to make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Convert add to be

```
def add(self, other):
    self.x = self.x + other.x
    self.y = self.y + other.y
```

That said, it's often useful to work with immutable objects, so why not have add return a new Position

```
def add(self, other):
    return Position(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

Then if you really want to get funky, why not override `__add__()`

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return Position(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

This will let you add two points together using the '+' operator.

```
a = Position(1, 1) 
b = Position(2, 3) 
c = a + b
```

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
class Position(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
       "Add two Positions and return a new one."
       return Position(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)   

    __radd__ = __add__

    def __iadd__(self, other):
       "In-place add += updates the current instance."
       self.x += other.x
       self.y += other.y
       return self

    def __str__(self):
       "Define the textual representation of a Position"
       return "Position(x=%d, y=%d)" % (self.x, self.y)

   __repr__ = __str__
```

Now your `Position` class can be added using the regular Python `+` operator and printed using the regular `print` statement:

```
A = Position(1, 2)
B = Position(2, 3)
A += B
print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not completely sure you actually want to change your point.  If you want to change your point, I would do

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def add(self,other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y
```

Alternatively, and more commonly (for Positions, I'd say, you'd want to get a new position)

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __add__(self,other):
        return Position(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

This way, if you overrode `__eq__`

```
Position(1,2) + Position(3,4) == Position(4,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to just `import numpy` and use `numpy.array` instead of rolling your own `Position` class.